# flatpak program - add to path such that terminal knows the program

Tags: paths, flatpak

I can usually fire op blender via the terminal by executing `blender`. This worked out of the box, when using snap. However, the version in snap was very old so I found a newer version in flatpak.

Blender is installed with flatpak only now, and sadly the terminal does not know the word anymore.
`Command 'blender' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install blender`

I see the program is in
`/var/lib/flatpak/app/org.blender.Blender/current/active/export/share/applications/`

[image]

I understand I need to do some path stuff in .bash_rc but after many attempts I would love your help

Comment: FYI Blender is still on the snap store (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/getting_started/installing/linux.html) but does not seem to officially support flatpak (https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/102949) so snap is probably the best place to go for the most up to date version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to run the command `flatpak run org.blender.Blender`.

You can call it with `blender`, by adding the following line to your `.bashrc`(note: it is NOT "bash_rc", which you mentioned in the question)

```
alias blender='env -u SESSION_MANAGER flatpak run org.blender.Blender'
```